# CodePush + React Native: How do I view my staging release?

Tags: react-native, code-push

I am trying to install https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push so that I can push without going through the app store.

I just ran `code-push release-react MyAppName ios --deploymentName Staging`. I also ran `code-push release-react MyAppName ios --deploymentName Production`. Both finished successfully

```
┌────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────┬──────────────────────┐
│ Name       │ Deployment Key                        │ Update Metadata                  │ Install Metrics      │
├────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ Production │ abc123-ER1Zk1llw5Apk3gI8HN37NyRzl4z0Z │ Label: v1                        │ No installs recorded │
│            │                                       │ App Version: 1.0                 │                      │
│            │                                       │ Mandatory: No                    │                      │
│            │                                       │ Release Time: 14 minutes ago     │                      │
│            │                                       │ Released By: edmundmai@gmail.com │                      │
├────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────┼──────────────────────┤
│ Staging    │ abc123xGp-l0eMKT0xH10_QxVQCkNyRzl4z0Z │ Label: v1                        │ No installs recorded │
│            │                                       │ App Version: 1.0                 │                      │
│            │                                       │ Mandatory: No                    │                      │
│            │                                       │ Release Time: 27 minutes ago     │                      │
│            │                                       │ Released By: edmundmai@gmail.com │                      │
└────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────┴──────────────────────┘
```

How do I run the build on my simulator or device now?

Comment: what do you really want ?

Comment: Is your staging version with the debug flag set as true ? Because when you are in debug mode it's not possible to see the code-push releases.

Comment: As long as you're testing a build with the staging deployment key set in your app, you should see that code push release